# preparedstatement, resultset, and query issue

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement, resultset

The method below should take two user inputs "low and "high" from a jsp page, and use them to get a list of properties that have a price that are between the "low" and "high".

One error that I see in my tomcat-log is:

*MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the 
manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to 
use near 'BETWEEN 100000.0 and 300000.0' at line 1*

100000.0 and 300000.0 is the input I typed in.

```
public static ArrayList<Property> search(double low, double high) {
ConnectionPool pool = ConnectionPool.getInstance();
Connection connection = pool.getConnection();
PreparedStatement ps = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

    String query = "select * from properties"
        + "WHERE price BETWEEN ? and ?";

    try {
        ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setDouble(1, low);  //this should set user input = ?
        ps.setDouble(2, high); //this should set user input = ?
        rs = ps.executeQuery();

        ArrayList<Property> list = new ArrayList<>();

        while (rs.next()) {     
            Property p = new Property();    
            p.setName(rs.getString("name"));
            p.setPrice(rs.getDouble("price"));
            list.add(p);
        }       
        return list;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        return null;
    } finally {
        DBUtil.closeResultSet(rs);
        DBUtil.closePreparedStatement(ps);
        pool.freeConnection(connection);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a space in your query

```
String query = "select * from properties"
    + " WHERE price BETWEEN ? and ?";
```

as you had it the word would become `propertiesWHERE`

Comment: Never in my life I felt so stupid. I was trying all day to fix this, thinking my code/logic had an issue. Thanks.

Comment: Happens to us all

Comment: @Brad This is a nice moment when you realise the power of something like `System.out.println` (or a decent logging API) and some debugging :P (no offense intended)

Comment: @ScaryWombat Yeah, but when was the last time you posted it on SO ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer haha, I know, and believe me I tried to use them, but netbeans and tomcat don't give the best outputs.